# Performing Text Analytics on a text Column in Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text-analysis

I have imported a CSV file into a dataframe in R and one of the columns contains Text.

I want to perform analysis on the text. How do I go about it?

I tried making a new dataframe containing only the text column.

```
OnlyTXT= Txtanalytics1 %>%
  select(problem_note_text)
View(OnlyTXT).
```

Comment: What are you trying to get out of the text column?

Comment: Get fancy, count the characters `table(unlist(strsplit(OnlyTXT[, 1], "")))`.

Comment: I am trying to extract each row text in the column and parse the text to get frequency of words and also to clean the text data by removing stop words and by stemming.

Comment: Check out the `tm` and `SnowballC` packages. They have pretty much everything you need.

Comment: I used the "DataframeSource(OnlyTXT)" to get each row of text in the dataframe as a separate document. I want to perform analysis on these words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could get you started.

```
install.packages("gtools", dependencies = T)
library(gtools) # if problems calling library, install.packages("gtools", dependencies = T)
library(qdap) # qualitative data analysis package (it masks %>%)
library(tm) # framework for text mining; it loads NLP package
library(Rgraphviz) # depict the terms within the tm package framework
library(SnowballC); library(RWeka); library(rJava); library(RWekajars)  # wordStem is masked from SnowballC
library(Rstem) # stemming terms as a link from R to Snowball C stemmer
```

The following assumes your text variable (your OnlyTXT) is in data frame "df" labeled "text".

```
df$text <- as.character(df$text) # to make sure it is text

# prepare the text by lower casing, removing numbers and white spaces, punctuation and unimportant words.  The `tm::`prefix is being cautious.
df$text <- tolower(df$text)
df$text <- tm::removeNumbers(df$text)
df$text <- str_replace_all(df$text, "  ", "") # replace double spaces with single space
df$text <- str_replace_all(df$text, pattern = "[[:punct:]]", " ")

df$text <- tm::removeWords(x = df$text, stopwords(kind = "SMART"))

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$text)) # turn into corpus

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus) # create tdm from the corpus

freq_terms(text.var = df$text, top = 25) # find the 25 most frequent words
```

There is much more you can do with the `tm` package or the `qdap` package.

Comment: **qdap** shouldn't mask `%>%` as it imports it from dplyr via `\`%>%\` <- dplyr:\`%>%\``: https://github.com/trinker/qdap/blob/master/R/chaining.R